# WPF Access parent data context in ListView template and it be the same instance of the resource

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

```
<Grid x:Name = "Parent" DataContext = "{StaticResource vm}"> 
   <ListView ItemsSource = {Binding vm.someCollection>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <someUserontrol DependencyProperty = {Binding vm} AnohtherDependencyPropery = {Binding} 
            </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>

<Grid/>
```

Let's say I have a list view and the Item template is using a user control has a property that has a type to that of a data context of an ancestor control. How to I pass this context to the template and it is the same object instance? Everything I have tried passes a new instance of that object type and I need to work with the same instance. The example above is a simplification of what I'm working with, the Grid is actually several levels above the listview (like great great great ancestor). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid x:Name = "Parent" DataContext = "{StaticResource vm}"> 
   <ListView ItemsSource = {Binding someCollection>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <someUserontrol DependencyProperty = {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext} AnohtherDependencyPropery = {Binding} 
            </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
<Grid/>
```